# I keep getting 0x488144 and another one before my output

Tags: c++

[Picture of error when input is jst L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgzwJ.png)

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string student_name;
    cout << "Enter student name\n";
    cin >> student_name;
    string student_surname;
    cout << "Enter Student surname\n";
    cin >> student_surname;
    string student_id;
    cout << "Enter Student ID\n";
    cin >> student_id;
    string student_group;
    cout << "Enter Student Group\n";
    cin >> student_group;
    string Module_code;
    cout << "Enter Module Code\n";
    cin >> Module_code;
    float test1;
    cout << "Enter Test 1 mark\n";
    cin >> test1;
    float test2;
    cout << "Enter Test 2 mark\n";
    cin >> test2;
    float final_mark;
    final_mark = (test1 + test2) / 2;
    cin >> final_mark;
    string grade;

    if (final_mark >= 80) {
        grade = "A";
        cin >> grade;
    }
    else if (final_mark >= 70) {
        cout << "B";
        cin >> grade;
    }
    else if (final_mark >= 60) {
        grade = "C";
        cin >> grade;
    }
    else if (final_mark >= 50) {
        grade = "D";
        cin >> grade;
    }
    else if (final_mark >= 40) {
        grade = "E";
        cin >> grade;
    }
    else (final_mark <= 30);
    {
        grade = "F";
        cin >> grade;
    } /*final code*/ cout << "LOMKOWKING UNIVERSITY\n";

    cout << "ESWATINI CAMPUS\n";
    cout << "STUDENT RESULT\n";
    cout << "STUDENT NAME :" << cout << student_surname << student_name << endl;
    cout << "STUDENT ID :" << cout << student_id << endl;
    cout << "STUDENT GROUP :" << cout << student_group << endl;
    cout << "MODULE CODE :" << cout << Module_code << endl;
    cout << "Test 1 :" << cout << test1;
    cout << "Test 2" << cout << test2 << endl;
    cout << "Final Mark :" << cout << final_mark;
    cout << "Grade :" << cout << grade << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you look at your code, the weird 0x48144 comes right after "STUDENT NAME". Let's see what you print right after "STUDENT NAME": `cout << "STUDENT NAME: " << cout << student_surname`

Comment: Please reformat your code, indent by 4-spaces so it formats as fixed text or put `\`\`\`cpp` on the line above your code and `\`\`\`` on the line after for the same effect.

Comment: Why does that even compile? Wouldn't that require there to be some `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::ostream&)`?

Comment: you're outputting the address of std::cout, a heads up: unlearn "using namespace". Jason Turner explains it best "stop using using namespace" : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8

Comment: BTW (and not directly related to the question), assigning a value to `grade` immediately before `cin >> grade` does not look like it does something reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
string student_name;
cout<< "Enter student name\n";
cin>>student_name;
string student_surname;
cout<<"Enter Student surname\n";
cin>>student_surname;
string student_id;
cout<<"Enter Student ID\n";
cin>>student_id;
string student_group;
cout<<"Enter Student Group\n";
cin>>student_group;
string Module_code;
cout<<"Enter Module Code\n";
cin>>Module_code;
float test1;
cout<<"Enter Test 1 mark\n";
cin>>test1;
float test2;
cout<<"Enter Test 2 mark\n";
cin>>test2;
float avg;
avg = (test1 + test2) / 2;
string grade;

if(avg<=40){
    grade = "F";
}
else if(avg<=50 && avg>40){
    grade = "E";
}
else if(avg<=60 && avg>50){
    grade = "D";
}
else if(avg<=70 && avg>60){
    grade = "C";
}
else if(avg<80 && avg>70){
    grade = "B";
}
else if(avg>=80){
    grade = "A";
}

/*final code*/

cout<< "LOMKOWKING UNIVERSITY\n";
cout<<"ESWATINI CAMPUS\n";
cout<< "STUDENT RESULT\n";
cout<< "STUDENT NAME :" <<student_surname << " " <<student_name << endl;
cout<< "STUDENT ID :" <<student_id << endl;
cout<< "STUDENT GROUP :"<<student_group << endl;
cout<< "MODULE CODE :"<<Module_code << endl;
cout<< "Test 1 :" <<test1<<endl;
cout<< "Test 2: "<<test2 << endl;
cout<< "Final score :"<<avg << endl;
cout<< "Grade :"<<grade<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

please, do not input "L" as a value to float variables (i.e. test1 and test2)